# Is it safe to cast a heap allocated pointer to a pointer to a VLA?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer, c99

If I've got a pointer to some heap allocated space that represents a typical
row-major two dimensional array, is it safe to cast this pointer to an
equivalent pointer to a VLA for convenient sub-scripting? Example:

```
//
// Assuming 'm' was allocated and initialized something like:
//
// int *matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * rows * cols);
//
// for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
//     for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
//         matrix[r * cols + c] = some_value;
//     }
// }
//
// Is it safe for this function to cast 'm' to a pointer to a VLA?
//
void print_matrix(int *m, int rows, int cols) {
    int (*mp)[cols] = (int (*)[cols])m;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            printf(" %d", mp[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I've tested the code above. It seems to work, and it makes sense to me that it should work, but is it safe, defined behavior?

In case anyone is wondering, the use case here is I'm receiving data from a
file/socket/etc that represents a row-major 2D (or 3D) array and I'd like to use
VLA's to avoid manually calculating indexes to the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined if `cols` is 0 or smaller. C11 made support for VLAs optional (see e.g. [here](http://compgroups.net/comp.std.c/why-are-vlas-optional-in-c11/2616013), and you tagged your question C99, where they’re required), if they’re not supported, the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined to 1 (cf. C11 6.10.8.3 p1).

This aside, you’re safe.

Thanks to Ouah and Alter Mann!

Comment: Wait, maybe you're not. Forgot strict aliasing. Damn.

Comment: no problem with aliasing, the array objects are accessed as `int` in all cases.

Comment: VLA is optional so compilers for embedded platforms don't have the burden to implement it if they don't want

Comment: C11 made support for VLAs optional (don’t know why): [Some good reasons](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c/AoB6LFHcd88/BvA4NiBe2mcJ)

Comment: Didn't realize VLA's were optional in C11. Interesting. Maybe I shouldn't be trying to use them all over the place...

Comment: @epicbrew, any compiler that also implements C99 is save for use with VLA. They were made optional in the hope to get those compilers that aren't yet C99 to modern C. Probably just wishful thinking.

Comment: @ouah, re: "object are accessed as int". Not exactly, l-value of object of type 'int[cols]' is accessed by 'mp[r]'. Object of this type does not exist thus there is UB there due to violation of strict aliasing rules